# JavaScript .selectedIndex only changes text value rather than actually selecting option

Tags: javascript, forms

*** EDIT - Switching to Chrome from Firefox 52.0.1 (32-bit) solved this problem **

I'm trying to speed up some data entry in some accounting software and have code to input details into a form to generate an invoice. The problem is with the select box.

```
document.getElementById('invoice_bank_account_id').selectedIndex = 2;
```

Which correctly sets the option of a dropdown menu to what I need.

However this only changes the text, when I click on the submit button for the form in question it behaves as if I had never changed the selected option and defaults to the first option in the dropdown list. I have to physically select and click for it to 'update' properly.

What do I need to do after selecting my option for it to work on form submission?

I also tried various combinations such as

```
document.getElementById('invoice_bank_account_id').options[2].selected = true;
```

... with the same result.

The code of the form is:

```
<fieldset id="advanced_options_fieldset" class="blockf">
<div id="advanced_options">
<p><label for="invoice_bank_account_id">Bank account</label><select id="invoice_bank_account_id" name="invoice[bank_account_id]">
<option selected="selected" value="385057" data-currency="GBP">Customer Deposits</option>
<option value="164288" data-currency="GBP">Business Current Account</option>
<option value="327151" data-currency="GBP">Deposit Account</option>

</p>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

I also tried by referencing the value of the option as well but that didn't work. I'm obviously missing something.

Thanks in advance, this is my first post on the forum.

Comment: Try also setting the value property to the inner HTML of the option.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There's no `</select>` tag. I wouldn't do a thing until that is corrected.

Comment: ...ultimately, I can't reproduce the issue in Firefox or Chrome. Both are sending the value of the `.selectedIndex` that was set. You're going to need to provide a full demonstration and tell us what browser you're using.

Comment: As squint says, the closing tag for a [*select element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element) is not optional, so browsers will error correct the markup and so may close the select before the options are added (or not).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. You were right I didn't include the </select> tag here although it was in the original HTML, I was trying to cut down the code and deleted it by accident. I have tried it in Chrome and it does actually work, I was using Firefox 52.0.1 (32-bit) - should have checked in another browser before posting the question I guess.

Comment: Should I mark this as solved or just delete the post? I've edited the question for now

Comment: You can post your own answer, which is what I would do and have done in the past. Then you can mark it correct after a certain time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply switching to Chrome this solved the problem. I was using Firefox 52.0.1 (32-bit) and Chrome 56.0.2924.87

Comment: You drop support for firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the value instead:

```
document.getElementById('invoice_bank_account_id').value = "327151"; 
// (Deposit Account)
```